# Default highlight colors in custom buttons

Tags: android, button, colors, selector, highlight

So, I have this app where I have custom radio buttons to select a theme and I wanted to have a border to the selected theme. So i made a copy of something like the android internal btn_default_normal_disable_focused.9 and used it in my application.

The result is something like this:

[image: Theme select]

(here the second theme is selected - white on black background)

This works fine and I was happy with the result. The problem is that if someone has different theme (for example a friend of mine has all oranges replaced with blue) this color doesn't fit! I've been trying to use the android drawables directly but with no luck, since they are all private.

Any suggestions? Should I change the theme select to something else that can use default colors? Can I get the drawable for the theme? I would be happy if I could at least get the blue color and use it in my custom selector!

Thanks!